# How can I tell CMake to only generate configuration for a subset of the targets of a project?

Tags: cmake

Currently, if I have a large CMakeLists.txt file (with a lot of `add_subdirectory` and `add_executable` calls), then it will generate configuration for all targets referred to by the parent CMakeLists.txt file. Is there a way to let CMake know to only generate configuration for a subset of targets?

I tried adding a custom target to compile only subset of targets, but CMake stills configures/generates for all of them.

Comment: No there isn't; You need to add this logic to the project yourself using e.g. a bool cache variable to conditionally add some parts of your project... Depending on the condition you may also be able to use cmake variables as condition, e.g. `if(WIN32) add_executable(windows_only_exe ...) endif()`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want configuration to be generated for a target, you have to omit configuration of that target from the CMake configuration by doing things like wrapping it in `if()` blocks and defining an `option()` for whether to generate it (the "it" being the definition of the target (`add_library`/`add_executable`), and any modification to it, such as `set_target_properties`, etc.).

If what you really want is for the target to not be part of the "all" target (to not be built when you don't specify which targets to build with [`--target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-t) or an analogous buildsystem argument), then use [the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html), which you can also set as an argument of `add_library`, `add_executable`, or `add_subdirectory`. Note that [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) also supports `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, and so does `FetchContent_Declare` [since 3.28](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.28.html#modules).

If your problem is that you're using a project with a large list of targets and you only want to build a subset of them and you're annoyed at having to manually specify which ones to build and such in your build command, then I'd recommend to instead use [CMake's presets feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) and define a build preset using the `targets` property.

There are good use-cases for wanting to do this with `if()` and `option()` though. For example, in one of my projects, I do it to avoid defining a Python bindings target and the corresponding `FetchContent` call to fetch the Python binding library when the user doesn't explicitly specify that they want to build Python bindings.